# Internal Server Error (Spring MVC 4.0)

Tags: spring-mvc, netbeans-8

I'm working on Spring MVC Framework and the IDE I've been using is NetBeans. I've been facing problem since last full week and that has stiffed my mind and I'm now in front of world (Hope today's night I'll go to bed with smile). Here is the [Snapshot of Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDDHc.png)

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>WELCOME</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action = "AddNumbersFunction">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> First Number: </td>
                    <td> <input type = "text" name = "num1"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Second Number: </td>
                    <td> <input type = "text" name = "num2"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td> <input type = "submit" name = "SubmitButton" value = "Add Numbers"> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MainCtrl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MainCtrl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

MainCtrl-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">


    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package = "com.MAKaey"></ctx:component-scan>

    <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name = "prefix">/WEB-INF/jsp</property>
        <property name = "suffix">.jsp</property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

AddController.java

```
package com.MAKaey;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class AddController {

    @RequestMapping("/AddNumbersFunction")
    public void add(){

        System.out.println("I'm Here!");
    }
}
```

The Problem is when I run the project, the following Error (javax.servlet.ServletException) [Exception's Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcUiW.png)
    Even no any text fields are displayed, as you run the project the first page that is displayed is that error.
    Kindly help me of this! Thanks!

Comment: Can you add stacktrace of error(which you can see in netbean console)?

Comment: Netbeans has showing no error! The error is displaying in the Browser.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`<ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
<ctx:component-scan base-package = "com.MAKaey"></ctx:component-scan>`

to

```
<tx:annotation-config></tx:annotation-config>
<tx:component-scan base-package = "com.MAKaey"></tx:component-scan>
```

Becuase you are importing using `xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"` here